# WebDriver exceptions are occurring during parallel Execution when executing in Browserstack cross mobile testing platform

Tags: parallel-processing, cucumber, testng, appium, execution

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session not started or terminated (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-AI87CII4', ip: '192.168.43.101', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_261'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {64bit: false, acceptSslCert: false, acceptSslCerts: false, adbExecTimeout: 120000, appActivity: biz.tikme.activities.Splash..., appPackage: biz.tikme, autoGrantPermissions: true, automationName: uiautomator2, browserstack.is_hub_canary: false, browserstack.minOSVersion: 4.4, bundleID: biz.tikme, bundleId: biz.tikme, chromeOptions: {w3c: false}, customFullReset: true, detected_language: selenium/3.141.59 (java win..., device: google pixel 3, deviceName: Android, enablePerformanceLogging: false, javascriptEnabled: true, mobile: {browser: mobile, version: Google Pixel 3-9.0}, nativeWebScreenshot: true, newCommandTimeout: 0, new_bucketing: true, noReset: false, orientation: PORTRAIT, orig_os: android, osVersion: 9.0, os_version: 9.0, platform: ANDROID, platformName: Android, projectName: TikMe-HyperLocalAutomationP..., realMobile: true, systemPort: 8201, udid: 88MX01NAS, uiautomator2ServerLaunchTimeout: 60000, version: }
Session ID: 44f96cd0f831bf10a228bfa2c6a46876d1278e15
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:45)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.InteractsWithApps.closeApp(InteractsWithApps.java:140)
at com.tikme.hyperlocal.mobileautomation.base.Base.closeapp(Base.java:98)
at com.tikme.hyperlocal.mobileautomation.step.Hooks.quit(Hooks.java:82)

````
```   *** if(new GlobalParams().getmedium().equals("BrowserStack"))
            {
                 int i = 0;
                 while(i<3)
                 {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        new TestUtils().log().info("going to reset the app");
                        manager.getDriver().resetApp(); // This is the method which throws the exception
                        new TestUtils().log().info("app is resetted successfully");                     
                        break;
                        
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        new TestUtils().log().fatal("tried"+" "+i+" "+"time to reset the app but failed.");
                        i++;
                    }
         
                 }
                
            }
            
            new Base().closeapp();
        }
    } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

If resetApp() doesn't work, you can try to add it as a capability for the DesiredCapabilities object

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, false);
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, true);
```

those two lines will reset your app, here is the documentation http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/reset-strategies/#reset-strategies

Comment: Actually I am using browserstack for mobile testing and those two above capabilities are not supported in browserstack. Thats why I have been using resetApp method. Sometimes it showing the error at the resetApp line sometimes at driver.quit() method.

Comment: But why would you reset it by yourself if they ensure you that after each session they are resetting and cleaning the device? https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/capabilities - Appium's fullreset capability will not work as we always uninstall the app and clean up the device at the end of each session